# how to expand directory with awk files

Tags: vim, awk

I have created a scriptdirectory

```
let $MYSCRIPTS = $VIM."/vimfiles/my_scripts-docs"
```

($VIM = C:\Program Files\Vim)

this works fine:

`exe "e ".expand('$MYSCRIPTS/vim-calc_vb.txt')`

This doesn't work and I can't find out why:

```
exe "!awk -f ".expand('$MYSCRIPTS/my-awk-script.awk')  
exe "!awk -f ".expand('$MYSCRIPTS\my-awk-script.awk')
```

error:
awk: fatal: can't open source file 'C:/Program'
It works fine when I put the .awk file in the root but not when
I put it in a vim directory or whatever directory under C:\program files

Why does .txt files expand and .awk files not?
How can I let vim know where the awk file is under vimfiles?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why do you need `expand()` and not just

```
fnameescape($MYSCRIPTS.'/vim-calc_vb.txt')
```

(for the `exe "e"`) and

```
shellescape($MYSCRIPTS.'/my-awk-script.awk, 1)
```

(for `!awk …`)?

Based on your

> awk: fatal: can't open source file 'C:/Program'
>    It works fine when I put the .awk file in the root but not when
>    I put it in a vim directory or whatever directory under C:\program files

I see that absence of `shellescape()` is the problem here, not `expand()`, <s>but it does not make the former useful</s>. It is useful for changing `\` to `/` on windows. Just surround your `expand()` calls with `fnameescape()`/`shellescape(…, 1)`:

```
" None is needed here: `:e` expands `$` on its own
e $MYSCRIPTS/vim-calc_vb.txt

exe "!awk -f ".shellescape(expand('$MYSCRIPTS\my-awk-script.awk'), 1)
```

Comment: @Remonn Just as well as `expand('$MYSCRIPTS')`. First two are examples of *expressions* to put *instead of an expand() call*, not the commands themselves. Example usage is at the last code block.

Comment: Hi Zyx, I checked the awk command but it still gives the same error `awk: fatal: can't open source file 'C:/Program'`- It cannot expand the program files directory.

Comment: @Remonn What exactly did you check?

Comment: `exe "!awk -f ".shellescape(expand('$MYSCRIPTS\my-awk-script.awk'), 1)`

Comment: @Remonn If you change `awk -f` to `type` does this work (it should type file contents to the terminal)? I can’t check with awk (don’t have it under wine), but with `type` it works properly. Maybe it is exclusive `awk` problem.

Comment: Yes with `!type` it seems to work (but there is an error that the syntax of the command is not correct).

Comment: @Remonn I can’t fix bugs in awk. Problem here is that on Windows AFAIK command receives the whole command-line as one string and has to parse it on its own. Escaping scheme used by `shellescape()` is just a common convention (likely implemented in some library, but I am not sure). If awk does not follow it, I can’t help. You can replace `Program Files` with some weird short 8.3 filename (in wine it appeared to be `C:\PROG~FBU`), it won’t possibly contain spaces.

Comment: In dos/windows it is `C:\Progra~1` but this doesn't work as well. Some awk problem. Maybe someone else reading this has AWK on his disk. (btw when I write `@ZyX`and click on Add Comment, `@ZyX` is removed, what did I wrong?)

Comment: @Remonn It is explained in the help (`help` link below “Add Comment”, “Learn more…” link, [Replying in comments](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#link-comment-reply) section). Owner of the answer/question is *always* notified about the comment so no need to use `@ZyX`. Here `@user` is used (technically, actually it used differently) to make some person be notified about the reply (in some limited set of cases, read the help). // Github handles this in less limited and much more convenient fashion.

Comment: I had to double quote the path. This works `!awk -f "c:\Program Files\Vim\vimfiles\my_scripts-docs\my-awk-script.awk"` but I still can't find out how to expand the first part of the path using $MYSCRIPTS.

Comment: @Remonn It is very strange. What you did here is exactly what `shellescape()` does (BTW, check `echo shellescape(expand('$MYSCRIPTS\my-awk-script.awk'), 1)`, maybe it is misconfigured and actually does something else). Check everything for typos.

Comment: it gives the right path, `c:\Program Files\Vim\vimfiles\my_scripts-docs\my-awk-script.awk` no typos but not with double quotes. The path is single quoted. I note that it works with double quotes, not with single quotes.

Comment: @Remonn It means that it is misconfigured. See `:h 'shell'` and all underlying `'shell*'` options, they all must have default value for `cmd.exe` (usually marked as “MS-DOS and Win32 (when 'shell' …)” or written in the text). Problem may arise either from some configuration in vimrc or misconfigured at compile time (`Make_ming.mak` pulls default 'shell' option from build environment, but build environment here is linux, not windows). If you have `set shell=cmd.exe` in vimrc it should automatically set all other related options, but sometimes it fails to do so. At runtime this never works.

Comment: Found it!! You helped me resolving it. `shellslash` was set in a latex configuration.